# how to get the status of a file download in the browser using node.js

Tags: node.js

In index.js,I had used the below code for downloading a file and display the status of that file in the console.

But,now I'm trying to display the status of that file in the browser using node.js.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My index.js :

```
//Downloads the file and shows the status in the console
    var request = require('request');
    var progress = require('request-progress');
    var DOWNLOAD_DIR = '/usr/local/';
    var file_name = 'newgoogle.png' 

    var callback = function(state){
        console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
        console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
        console.log('percent', state.percent);

    } 

    progress(request('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'), {
        throttle:0,   
        delay: 0       
    })
    .on('progress', callback) 

    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name))
    .on('error', function (err) {
     console.log("error");  
    })
    .on('close', function (err){
    console.log("Download Complete"); 
    })

//Lists all the files and folders in the filesysytem 
app.get('/files', function(req, res) {


 var currentDir =  dir;
 var query = req.query.path || '';
 if (query) currentDir = path.join(dir, query);
 console.log("browsing ", currentDir);

 fs.readdir(currentDir, function (err, files) {
     if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      var data = [];
      files
      .filter(function (file) {
          return true;
      }).forEach(function (file) {
        try {
                var stats = fs.statSync(path.join(currentDir,file));
                var time = stats["atime"];
                var date = time.toString().substr(4,11);

                var isDirectory = fs.statSync(path.join(currentDir,file)).isDirectory();
                if (isDirectory) {
                  data.push({ Name : file,Date : date, IsDirectory: true, Path : path.join(query, file)  });
                } else {
                  var ext = path.extname(file);
                  if(program.exclude && _.contains(program.exclude, ext)) {
                    console.log("excluding file ", file);
                    return;
                  }       
                  data.push({ Name : file,Date:date, Ext : ext, IsDirectory: false, Path : path.join(query, file) });
                }

        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e); 
        }        

      });
      data = _.sortBy(data, function(f) { return f.Name});
      res.json(data);
  });
});
```

Here,in app.js I'm trying to display the data in the Data Table.

My app.js :

```
var currentPath = null;
   var options = {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
         "sScrollY":"250px",
      "fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
    var path = aData.Path;
    $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
        $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
            table.fnClearTable();
            table.fnAddData(data);
            currentPath = path;
        });


        $.get('/directory?path='+ path).then(function(data){        
            $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
           //$("#showDiv").hide();
         });         
    e.preventDefault();
    });
},



        "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"File Name", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
              } else {
                return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +"</a>";
              }
            }
          },
            {"sTitle":"Date",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                 return  data.Date;
             }else{
               return data.Date;

             } 
            }
          },
        {"sTitle":"Status",align: 'Center', "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head1", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                 return "";
             }else{
               return "";

             }
            }
          }
        ]   

     };

  var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable(options);

  $.get('/files').then(function(data){
      table.fnClearTable();
      table.fnAddData(data);
  });

$.get('/directory').then(function(data){        
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
   $("#showDiv").hide();
});
```

My current format :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), on your progress callback function, that's the correct way to maintain consistent communication between the client to the server.